# Appending to array while iterating over file using fgets

Tags: c, fgets

C newbie here.
I'm trying to append a files content to an array line by line by looping over it using `fgets` in a `while` loop.

When trying to access the array however I get a segmentation fault while accessing the array  on value `array[1]` or `array[2]`. When reading `array[3]` it does work. Am I doing something wrong?

Could someone point me into the right direction?
I'll leave my code below.

```
#include "library.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    char *array[] = {};
    int i = 0;
    
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        i++;
        array[i] = line;
    }
    printf("Line %d = %s\n", i , array[1]); //segmentation fault on array[1] and array[2] not on array[3]
}
```

Comment: `char *array[] = {};` what do you think this line does? Certainly doesn't allocate space, you have to use `malloc()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You only have 1 buffer `line[]` to store the line. You read every line into that same buffer and assign the address of that buffer to your array: `array[i] = line;` This means each elements will point to the same line. Additionally, `array` does not contain any space for these pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two bugs.

1. There is no memory for `array`
2. You keep storing the address of `line` into `array`. What you need is to get the content of `line` into the array.

Try like:

```
#define MAX_LEN 100

char line[MAX_LEN];
size_t capacity = 256;
char (*array)[MAX_LEN] = malloc(capacity * sizeof *array);
if (array == NULL)
{
    // Error
    // Add error handling or just:
    exit(1);
}
size_t i = 0;

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) 
{
    if (i == capacity) 
    {
        capacity = 2 * capacity;
        char (*tmp)[MAX_LEN] = realloc(array, capacity * sizeof *array);
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            // Error
            // Add error handling or just:
            exit(1);
        }
        array = tmp;
    }
    strcpy(array[i], line);
    ++i;
}

... do something with array ...

free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must dimension your array. Otherwise it will be dimentionned by its initializer. As your initializer is empty, your array is empty too.

So, it you want to be able to store, say, a hundred lines, you should write:

```
char *array[100] = {};
```

(I'm explaining this with a static dimension for the array, because the dynamic allocation approach is a bit more complex)

Then, when you write your line:

```
array[i] = line;
```

Do you realize that you're working with pointer?

**line** represents the address of the buffer where the characters of the **line** are stored. And you assign this address of the variable **line** to an array of pointers.

array[1] is the second pointer of your array of pointer. (because array indexation starts with 0 in C)
There is a segmentation because your array contains zero value, so you can't access the 2nd (non existing) value.

In addition, you assign always the same addres (the address of the variable **line** to every entry of your array.

In fact you've got only one **line** whose address you duplicate in your **array**

There are multiple errors that will prevent you from storing all the lines of the files in your array.

I'll edit this post ASAP to provide you with a working example of what you're trying to do.